# Windows Security - No control panel

Tags: windows, security

How would you restrict access to control panel / changing system files for a user on a PC?

Comment: Give him a limited user account? This site is meant for programming questions, not IT support.

Comment: With a group policy. Be sure and mention that when you post this on [su] where it belongs instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great [directions](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101869-local-group-policies-apply-all-users-except-administrators.html) on how to set up Group Policies for non-admin users or individual users.  Once you have set this up, you can follow the directions below.

Go to `User Configuration`, then `Administrative Templates`, then click `Control Panel`.  In the pane on the right you will see `Prohibit Access to the Control Panel`, Right click and select `Edit`.  Then click the `Enabled` radio button and then `OK`.

At this point the policy is in effect.  If you ever want to disable it, you can go back in the same way and set to `Not Configured`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look for a local security policy in gpedit.msc then User Configuration\AdministrativeTemplates\Start Menu & Taskbar